# CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch MS SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, view, ssms

Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 18 shows an error:

> CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in the batch

After executing the request, the following error appears:

> Incorrect syntax around the "select" keyword

```
create view revenue0 (supplier_no, total_revenue) as
    select
        l_suppkey,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount))
    from
        lineitem
    where
        l_shipdate >= '1996-05-01'
        and l_shipdate < dateadd(mm,3,cast('1996-05-01' as datetime))
    group by
        l_suppkey;


select
s_suppkey,
s_name,
s_address,
s_phone,
total_revenue
from
supplier,
revenue0
where
    s_suppkey = supplier_no
    and total_revenue = (
        select
            max(total_revenue)
        from
            revenue0
    )
order by
s_suppkey
option (maxdop 2)
drop view revenue0
```

UPD. I tried to run with this method:

```
create view revenue0 (supplier_no, total_revenue) as
    select
        l_suppkey,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount))
    from
        lineitem
    where
        l_shipdate >= cast('1996-05-01' as datetime)
        and l_shipdate < dateadd(mm, 3, cast('1996-05-01' as datetime))
    group by
        l_suppkey;

go
select
    s_suppkey,
    s_name,
    s_address,
    s_phone,
    total_revenue
from
    supplier,
    revenue0
where
    s_suppkey = supplier_no
    and total_revenue = (
        select
            max(total_revenue)
        from
            revenue0
    )
order by
    s_suppkey;

drop view revenue0;
```

But as a result of executing the request, an error is displayed:
Invalid object name "revenue0".
As soon as I didn't change my name. SQL all the same swears at this name.

UPD2. The question was solved independently. The topic is closed! Thank you all for your efforts!

Comment: Put the word `GO` after the view definition.

Comment: Can you tell me where exactly? I am not very good at SQL. I'll be very thankful!

Comment: `group by l_suppkey; GO`

Comment: Incorrect syntax around "go" construct.

Comment: you can't use "order by" in the view, redesign you view to not use it.

Comment: I am doing TPС-H test on MS SQL Management Studio. The problem is with request 15. He gives this error. The most I was able to achieve was empty output.I don’t know what could be a mistake. Since the rest of the other queries are working fine. But there were problems with that.

Comment: It's not clear why you're using a view here at all. If you want to introduce a named subquery for the use of a single following query, look at using a Common Table Expression (CTE). Also, please learn to use the explicit `JOIN` syntax, rather than comma joins in the `FROM` clause. explicit JOIN was added to the SQL Standard in **1992**.

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you the CREATE VIEW must be the only statement in a batch. A batch is ended in SQL Server with the "GO" keyword, as Gordon stated, so your code should look like this:

```sql
create view revenue0 (supplier_no, total_revenue) as
    select
        l_suppkey,
        sum(l_extendedprice * (1 - l_discount))
    from
        lineitem
    where
        l_shipdate >= '1996-05-01'
        and l_shipdate < dateadd(mm,3,cast('1996-05-01' as datetime))
    group by
        l_suppkey;

GO -- right here. This ends a batch. Must be on a new line, with no semi-color, or SQL gets pissy. 

select
    s_suppkey,
    s_name,
    s_address,
    s_phone,
    total_revenue
from
    supplier,
    revenue0
where
    s_suppkey = supplier_no
    and total_revenue = (
        select
            max(total_revenue)
        from
            revenue0
    )
order by
    s_suppkey
option (maxdop 2); 

drop view revenue0;
```

Comment: I am testing "
TPC-H Tests on MS-SQL-Server" this stuff: [link](https://github.com/huunghia160799/TPC-H-Dataset-Generator-MS-SQL-Server).
When executing this request, this should be: [link](https://github.com/huunghia160799/TPC-H-Dataset-Generator-MS-SQL-Server/blob/master/dbgen/answers/q15.out).

Comment: But I have, with your correction, after executing the SQL query, the output is an empty table. The request execution time is 0 seconds. It is not normal.

Comment: You can help remake this query to make it work: [link](https://github.com/huunghia160799/TPC-H-Dataset-Generator-MS-SQL-Server/blob/master/dbgen/queries_original/15.sql).

Comment: I already broke my whole head with him. But this particular query doesn't want to work. All the rest are working.